# Is there a helper for creating handlebars blocks in haml?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, handlebars.js

Because handlebars tags are evaluated after haml is compiled to html, and handlebars counts as plane text in haml you cannot indent logic

```
  {{#if misc}}
  %b Misc Products
  Total:
  {{misc_total}}
  {{#each misc}}
  {{price_charged}}
  {{notes}}
  {{/each}}
  {{/if}}
```

Which is hard to read.
I made a rails helper to make this better looking*.

```
def handlebars_helper(helper, &block)
  raise ArgumentError, "Missing block" unless block_given?
  open = ActiveSupport::SafeBuffer.new("{{##{helper}}}") # helper opening
  open.safe_concat capture(&block)
  open.safe_concat("{{/#{helper.split.first}}}") # helper closing
  concat(open)
end
```

which lets you write haml that looks like this

```
  - handlebars_helper 'if misc' do
    %b Misc Products
    Total:
    {{misc_total}}
    - handlebars_helper 'each misc' do
      {{price_charged}}
      {{notes}}
```

Has this been done before, or is there a better way for me to do it?

*this helper looks a bit messy, I'm not that comfortable with blocks how would I clean this up?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use HAML to generate handlebars code, you can use [hamlbars](https://github.com/jamesotron/hamlbars), which will provide you a few helpers to help facilitate indentation. Unfortunately you'll still be stuck with awkward indentation surrounding if/else.

I'd recommend [Emblem.js](https://github.com/machty/emblem.js) as an alternative... the syntax is closer to Slim than HAML, but there's gonna be no ugly helper code polluting your templates just to preserve indentation. Disclaimer: I wrote emblem.